# asp mvc IIS deployment issue: Compilation Error

Tags: vb.net, iis, web-deployment, iis-express, webdeploy

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -2146232576.

Comment: Try to give more information about the context next time.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 3/12/18**

It seems like you have read, or possibly write, locks on one or more files. Close the studio and verify that the source code repository don't have orphaned read/write locks. Also verify that any directories used for compilations don't have read locks. There used to be a weird Temporary ASP.NET-folder that was prone to locking files in the good old days.

**Previous response**

These are a few things that come to mind in my experience. I am assuming the deployment machine is a Windows Server of sorts.

- Check the expected .NET version by checking project properties in Visual Studio (or the Project-files if another editor is used).
- Compare with the installed version of .NET of the deployment machine. Framework on the deployment machine should equal to or greater than .
- Verify the chosen app pool is running the expected version (or change it) and recycle it.
- Make sure all the necessary assembly files (.DLLs) have been included on the deployment machine. A quick look into the BIN or DEBUG folder usually tells the story, but will generally also contains a whole lot more stuff. Sometimes too many assembly files removed during optimisation of the build.

A little bit of information about deployment OS and .NET versions would help.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and Rebuild your solution (under Build menu). If it gives you any compilation errors, correct them and build it again. That worked for me.